# How to make images enlarge on click using only javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am working on a course which requires all the work for this unit to be done with Javascript only. My goal is to make the images in my website's photo gallery enlarge when clicked. The problem is, the onload event does not seem to be working to add the event listeners to the images. There may be other bugs that you can find, but I can't think of any other problem that could be preventing the code from running. Here's what I've got:

```
var imgList = document.getElementsByTagName("IMG");

var btn = document.getElementByClassName("reset-btn");

function enlargeImg(img) {
  img.style.transform = "scale(1.5)";
  img.style.transition = "transform 0.25s ease";
  btn.style.visibility = "visible";
  btn.addEventListener("click", resetImg);
}

function resetImg(img) {
  img.style.transform = "scale(1)";
  img.style.transition = "transform 0.25s ease";
}

function init() {
  for (var i = 0; i < imgList.length; i++) {
    var img = imgList[i];
    img.addEventListener("click", enlargeImg);
  }
  
} 

body.addEventListener("load", init);
```

Comment: @Dren Yes. There is a **_Major_** difference!

Answer (score 0):

I refactored it a bit. I used event delegation adding the click event to the entire body and then used the target property.

```js
var imgList = document.querySelectorAll('img');
var btn = document.querySelector('.reset-btn');
var body = document.querySelector('body');


body.addEventListener("click", function(e){
  enlargeImg(e);
});

btn.addEventListener('click' , resetImg);

function enlargeImg(e) {
  let target = e.target;
  if(target.className === 'img'){
   target.style.transform = "scale(1.5)";
   target.style.transition = "transform 0.25s ease";
  
  }

}

function resetImg() {
  for (let i of imgList){
    i.style.transform = "scale(1)";
    i.style.transition = "transform 0.25s ease";
  }
}
```

```css
.reset-btn {
    margin-top: 200px;
}
```

```html
<body>

    

    
    <img class="img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1570824104453-508955ab713e?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=613&q=80">
    <img class="img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1557246565-8a3d3ab5d7f6?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80">
    <div>
    <button class="reset-btn">Reset</button>
    </div>

    

    <script type="text/javascript" src="Answer boiler.js"></script>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <!-- <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> -->
  </body>
```